# Installing Darknet's base system on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, mingw

I'm trying to install darknet (following the instructions on https://pjreddie.com/darknet/install/)

I ran:

```
git clone https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet.git
make
```

And am getting the following error:

```
gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -c ./src/gemm.c -o obj/gemm.o
In file included from ./src/utils.h:5,
                 from ./src/gemm.c:2:
include/darknet.h:6:10: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pthread.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:89: recipe for target 'obj/gemm.o' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [obj/gemm.o] Error 1
```

Comment: In which environment did you have gcc? Is it mingw or mingw-w64? Did you try msys2 or cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message, I did fix it by installing pthread package, see the picture.

[image: installation manager screenshot]